# Running tests with Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I am following guide from this official site: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup.html#running-tests

To create a test configuration in Android Studio, complete the following steps:

1. Open Run > Edit Configurations.
2. Add a new Android Tests configuration.
3. Choose a module.
4. Add a specific instrumentation runner:
5. android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
6. Run the newly created configuration.

now, 1. is OK, but where in 2. is "Android Tests" configuration?? I can add "Android Instrumented Tests", but then where can I add "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" in 5.?

Comment: android docs are really bad. I hardly ever use them.

Answer (score 0):

For 2, see below. This is not necessary for AS2.3 and above. If your Instrumentation tests inside `androidTest` folder, just right-click on the test name and select Run.

[image]

For 5, You need to add this in your gradle script as below.

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion  .........
     buildToolsVersion  .........

     defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion .....
       targetSdkVersion .....
       testApplicationId = 'your.package.name.test'
       testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"   
     }
}
```